# Mongo Template querying the wrong collection

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, multiple-databases, mongotemplate

I have a mongodb springboot application that is connected to 2 different databases, that have the same collection names and database names but different uris.

Here is my application.properties

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri = uri
spring.data.mongodb.secondDB.uri = uri
spring.data.mongodb.database = database_name
spring.data.mongodb.secondDB.database = database_name
```

My AppConfiguration file

```
@Configuration
public class MultipleMongoConfig {
    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "newdb1Properties")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.data.mongodb")
    public MongoProperties getNewDb1Props() throws Exception {
        return new MongoProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name = "newdb2Properties")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.data.mongodb.secondDB")
    public MongoProperties getNewDb2Props() throws Exception {
        return new MongoProperties();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "newdb1MongoTemplate")
    public MongoTemplate newdb1MongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new MongoTemplate(newdb1MongoDatabaseFactory(getNewDb1Props()));
    }

    @Bean(name ="newdb2MongoTemplate")
    public MongoTemplate newdb2MongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new MongoTemplate(newdb2MongoDatabaseFactory(getNewDb2Props()));
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public MongoDatabaseFactory newdb1MongoDatabaseFactory(MongoProperties mongo) throws Exception {
        return new SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory(
                mongo.getUri()
        );
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoDatabaseFactory newdb2MongoDatabaseFactory(MongoProperties mongo) throws Exception {
        return new SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory(
                mongo.getUri()
        );
    }
```

Then I set up config files for each data source

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = {"com.example.app.firstDatabse.Repository"},
mongoTemplateRef = "newdb1MongoTemplate"
)
public class NewDb1Config {
}
```

and

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = {"com.example.app.secondDatabse.Repository"},
mongoTemplateRef = "newdb2MongoTemplate"
)
public class NewDb1Config {
}
```

For Model I have the following

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToSting
@Document(collection = "coll")
public class FirstModel{

@Id
public String id;
@Field("f_name")
public String firstName;
@Field("l_name")
public String lastName;
@Field("age")
public int age;
@Field("gender")
public String gender;
}
```

and my second Model is the same

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToSting
@Document(collection = "coll")
public class SecondModel{

@Id
public String id;
@Field("f_name")
public String firstName;
@Field("l_name")
public String lastName;
@Field("age")
public int age;
@Field("gender")
public String gender;
}
```

My controller

```
@ResController
@RequestMapping("/controller")
public class Controller{

@Autowired
private FirstDataabseRepository repo;

@Autowired
private SecondDataabseRepository repo;

@Resource
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

@RequestMapping("/findByName")
public List<SecondModel> findByName(){
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria = Criteria.where("f_name").is("John");
Query q = new Query(criteria);

List<SecondModel> results = mongoTemplate.find(q,SecondModel.class);

return results;
}
}
```

So the results show the results of the first collection not the second one. What do I need to do for mongoTemplate to query the second collection not the first one.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**
I have to add a qualifier and have a mongoTemplate for each collection

```
@ResController
@RequestMapping("/controller")
public class Controller{

@Autowired
private FirstDataabseRepository repo;

@Autowired
private SecondDataabseRepository repo;

@Resource
@Qualifier(value="newdb1MongoTemplate")
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

@Resource
@Qualifier(value="newdb2MongoTemplate")
private MongoTemplate mTemplate;

@RequestMapping("/findByName")
public List<SecondModel> findByName(){
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria = Criteria.where("f_name").is("John");
Query q = new Query(criteria);

List<SecondModel> results = mTemplate.find(q,SecondModel.class);

return results;
}
}
```